# Directed acyclic graph with distributed graph nodes

Tags: c#, graph

I'm interested of setting up calculations through an acyclic directed graph, whose calculation nodes shall be distributed across different processes/servers.

For a simple example, imagine I'm setting up a somewhat stupid graph to calculate "x + 2x":

[image: Example graph layout]

A) Node which receives numeric input from some external source, and forwards that on to its dependents

B) Node which gets the value of its dependency, and multiplies it by 2

C) Node which gets values of two dependencies, and adds them together

```
interface INode
{
  double calculate();
}

class A : INode
{
  private double _value;

  public void ReceiveInput(double value) {
    _value = value;
    // Notify some graph runner that this node has changed, i.e.
    // calculate() shall be invoked on this node and its dependents
  }

  public double calculate() => _value;
}

class B : INode
{
  private INode _a;

  public double calculate() => 2.0 * _a.calculate();
}

class C {
  private INode _a;
  private INode _b;

  public double calculate() => _a.calculate() + _b.calculate();
}
```

I'm trying to come up with a clever mechanism of managing calculations in topological order here.

For example, I'd need to make sure that when calculates, B calculates before C does (and C "knows" the most recent values of A and B, when calculating).

Since all nodes would live on different servers, this may be a little annoying. I might need to replicate the graph layout on each of the 3 servers; where e.g. server C only runs the actual implementation of node C, and has proxy implementations of nodes A and B (which purely rely on messaging from the other nodes for their results).
At the same time, node A might trigger several times before node B or C even receive the message, so I may also need to version-stamp each calculation cycle and ensure proxy nodes receive updates in their expected sequence order.

It seems solvable, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel here if I don't need to.

I suspect my problem is one that has already been solved by some smarter person - however, I haven't been able to find much in terms of practical implementations yet when searching for "distributed acyclic directed graph" and related terms.

Are there any commonly used/known approaches and algorithms for running a DAG with distributed nodes?

Comment: Not sure but try ```akka```

Comment: It sounds like you need to produce a hierarchical form of the graph, so that the top level contains the root nodes and the bottom level the final nodes. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with that concept (hierarchical form), sounds like that's more of a tool to subdivide a large graph into smaller subgraphs (google suggests mostly applications for visualization)? The "only" hard requirement for me is execution/traversal in topological order